# Finding The Average on Python

Tags: python, average

What is the average value of the numbers in the field [Num] in the range (3987) and (5026) inclusive?

The field is below it is field [4] on excel.

```
**amount       code    quan val     number  Random**
2.11    I[N8U7]:75  184 Blue    2254    Potato
3.13    Z[V0L8]:64  131 Blue    6349    Carrot
4.24    B[Y1U2]:38  56  Blue    4164    Mushrooms
7.32    T[Z7N0]:67  329 Red     2079    Pear
9.1     C[T8C5]:83  344 Blue    1045    Apple
11.17   M[P4J9]:38  267 Blue    1254    Strawberry
2.21    E[S1G7]:62  446 Red     2223    Vanilla
1.41    W[M4M5]:96  8   Red     6745    Juice
2.31    W[P3E1]:24  215 Red     1223    Orange
0.12    E[M5K0]:78  424 Blue    2385    Pineapple
3.91    A[A9M2]:33  367 Red     3354    Grape
3.1     W[N2E2]:70  121 Blue    7716    Watermelon
10.21   J[H2W8]:17  253 Red     1017    Yogurt
5.1     G[K5L5]:08  216 Red     1039    Peppers
1.14    V[Z2C3]:L75 419 Blue    2520    Onions
1.02    Q[I1I2]:20  380 Red     2700    Chocolate
0.19    S[P1X2]:43  133 Blue    3171    Cheese
7.21    Z[B2E3]:46  126 Blue    2971    Ham
10.21   L[F6V1J:28  249 Red     7574    Blueberry
1.02    X[B0N3]:65  243 Blue    3441    Water
```

I have tried the following code and I cannot figure out what else to do. Thanks in advance

```
file=open ('3114644b.csv','r')

def mylist():
    alist=[]
    for line in file:
        field = line.split(',')
        if field[0]=='bid' or field[0]=='leave':
            alist.append(float(field[4]))
    return alist

blist=mylist()
total = 0
count = 0
for num in blist:
    total +=  num
    count += 1

average = total / count

print ("the average of the values)

file.close
```

Comment: I fixed your indentations, but you'll need to add the `"` and `.close()` *call* parenthesis yourself.

Comment: Thank you Martin Pieters

Comment: To find the average, you can just do `avg = sum(blist)/len(blist)`

Comment: @karthikr can you try modify the code for me please? I am a beginner in Python so I don't fully understand it.

Comment: Is this Python 2 or 3?

Comment: @MartijnPieters It is Python 3.2.3

Comment: @AlanSmith: Check, adjusted my answer accordingly.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I put that code in i keep getting this error  "_csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)"

Comment: Your definition of `mylist` is wrong. That function cannot access the value you gave to `file` because you should pass it as **an argument**. It will never load your file in this way.

Comment: @AlanSmith: Exactly, the original version was for Python 2, and opened the file in binary mode. The updated version for Python 3 uses text mode.

Comment: @MartijnPieters So how do I fix the error? IF you can make changes to the code if they need to be any

Comment: @AlanSmith: You still get the error, even with the `open('3114644b.csv', newline='')` version? I tested the code against your sample data (with extra columns set to 0), and I see no such problems.

Comment: @AlanSmith: Are you certain that you *restarted* python properly and are running the *new* code? The error you show only occurs when you open the file using `'rb'` as the mode.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I closed Python and I copied the new code you have put and now that error is gone but I don't get an answer it just comes blank.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I will edit my question and I'll put all the fields I have in my Excel file.

Comment: @AlanSmith: Then *no rows* matched, none of the rows had `bid` or `leave` in `row[0]`. Can you post the first few rows of your CSV file please so we can see what is *in* the file?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I screenshot my file and I will upload it now.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I will upload it just getting used to Windows 8 at the moment

Comment: @AlanSmith: Just open the file in a text editor and copy the first few lines, and paste them here in your question.

Comment: @MartijnPieters That is what my file is like the "amount       code    quan val     number  Random" are the fields

Comment: @AlanSmith: Then *why* are you testing if `field[0] == 'bid' or field[0] == 'leave'`?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Made a mistake with that. Sorry

Comment: @AlanSmith: Is there a row condition at all? Or all all rows considered?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Considered

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html), it was designed for a task like this:

```
import csv

total = count = 0

with open('3114644b.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader, None)  # skip the first row of headers

    for row in reader:
        total += float(row[4])
        count += 1

if count:
    # only calculate the average if there was actually anything in the file
    average = total / count
    print('The average of the values is {}'.format(average))
```

The above code also uses the file as a context manager (with the `with` statement); as soon as the `with` block has completed, the file is closed for you, automatically.

In your version, you tried to close the file manually, but only managed to reference the `.close()` method, not actually call it.

We also don't read all values into a list, not when you can instead just sum the values and keep a count of how many values you summed. This uses much less memory and makes processing even huge CSV files fast and efficient.

For your sample data, the above code outputs:

> The average of the values is 3261.2

Comment: Should be `if count` rather than `if total`, because the average could very well be `0`.

Comment: @ThijsvanDien: Indeed, I wanted to avoid a `ZeroDivisionError` and then testing for `count` makes more sense. The input values are all in positive integers though in a specific range though.

Comment: @ThijsvanDien: Perhaps, I felt in a ask-to mood here after another learner wanted to avoid `try`..`except` statements..

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version that does not use the `cvs` module. (note that it is encouraged you learn how to use suitable modules if present for each task)

```
data = []

# This next line closes the file as soon as the block ends (as Martijn suggests)
with open ('3114644b.csv','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        field = line.split(',')
        if field[0] in {'bid', 'leave'}:
            # Note that the 4th column you want to refer to is actually the list
            # list elemnt with index 3, not 4. List indexes start with 0
            data.append(float(field[3]))

# The 'sum()' function is the best choice for your problem as karthirk suggested
# The 'len()' function is a built-in function that returns the number of items
# a list has
average = sum(data)/len(data)

print ("The average of the values is %f" % average)
```